# DB Link Query Error while writing Trigger Function

Tags: database, postgresql, dblink

I am using PSQL 9.6 and trying to write a TRIGGER. Now issue is I am facing the error in the following query and the terminal output isn't verbose enough to determine where I am going wrong with this query.

The Function goes like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_dblink_func()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  perform dblink_exec("insert into Some_Table select * from dblink( 'host=SOMEPRODSERVER dbname=DBNAME user=USERNAME password=PASSWORD', 'select id,name,helpline,email,created_at,updated_at') as sourceTable (id integer,name character varying,helpline character varying,email character varying,created_at timestamp with time zone,updated_at timestamp with time zone) on conflict(id) do update set id=excluded.id,name=excluded.name,helpline=excluded.helpline,email=excluded.email,created_at=excluded.created_at,updated_at=excluded.updated_at");

  perform dblink_disconnect();
   RETURN NULL;
   END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The output I am getting while I execute this function is this

```
LINE 5:   perform dblink_exec("insert into TABLENAME sel...
                  ^
CREATE FUNCTION
```

So I am confused as to what the error could be.
TIA

Comment: That is when you create the function, not when you execute it.  And that is not the entire message, the message starts with `NOTICE:  identifier "..." will be truncated to "..."` (the ellipsis are mine).  The fact that you use double quotes means that that entire 'query' is being treated as one SQL identifier (for example, a column name) not as a string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm so confused, coz I've tried splitting your dblink query into small steps, and I see that there's some issues in the select syntax (+ using of double quotes instead of single quotes):

```
INSERT INTO
    some_table
SELECT *
    FROM DBLINK('host=SOMEPRODSERVER dbname=DBNAME user=USERNAME password=PASSWORD',
                'SELECT id,name,helpline,email,created_at,updated_at') --<< here's not table with "FROM statement"
        AS sourcetable (id INTEGER,
                        name CHARACTER VARYING,
                        helpline CHARACTER VARYING,
                        email CHARACTER VARYING,
                        created_at TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
                        updated_at TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE)
ON CONFLICT(id) DO UPDATE SET
                              id=excluded.id,
                              name=excluded.name,
                              helpline=excluded.helpline,
                              email=excluded.email,
                              created_at=excluded.created_at,
                              updated_at=excluded.updated_at
```

And, according to the description, it is not clear for what action this trigger should fire. Can you split your code into small steps and provide some more info? Here is a [dbfiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=2a2d3f1f6746f32be68feba48dbb96af), that you can improve with your data